# AWS get parameter from parameter store and secretmanager not working in test env

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jestjs, aws-ssm

I have the below code. The same code works in dev env but it is stuck forever in test env. The same is happening while retrieving secret from secret manager. In both environments, it is able to print region and paramName, and it is the same for both env. But still while running this code during testing, it is stuck at ssmClient.getParameter.

```
const getParamsFromAws = (paramName) => {
  const ssmClient = new AWS.SSM({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  });
console.log("In get params")
  return ssmClient
    .getParameter({
      Name: paramName,
      WithDecryption: true,
    })
    .promise()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log("Data is "+ data)
      return JSON.parse(data.Parameter.Value);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err.message;
    });
};
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors? It is hard to tell whats go wrong without it. But If you get it to work in one env and not in another maybe it has to do with iam rights.

Comment: Just stuck for ever. When i try to print aws credentials, it is able to get it. Only problem executing this code while running test cases using "npm run test". Not sure why.. Even tried passing accessKey, secretAccessKey while getting client. Still stuck

Comment: Maybe try to see if you can ran another command to the ssmclient to understand where the issues is.